# How to get text value of column were date is date specified

Tags: excel

For example

```
01/01/2014  Año Nuevo 2013 
01/01/2014  Año Nuevo 2013 
01/01/2014  Año Nuevo 2013 
01/01/2014  Año Nuevo 2013 
01/01/2014  Año Nuevo 2013
```

I want to add a function which looks up 01/01/2014 on a new sheet and returns "Año Nuevo 2013" from the sheet with the data on, as example above shows

What function can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Is your problem focus on getting value from specified column/row or is it about date format?

Comment: i want to get a value from column 2 where date = date I specify

Comment: If your dates differ from each other then as Jochem awnsered `=vlookup()` is what you are looking for. If you have more preferences you need to give us more information.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what exactly you try to accomplish, but `vlookup()` allows you to look up values and return them in a specific sheet. However, as said I am unsure what you are trying to accomplish and therefore it is hard to draft a proper answer.